# How to add DateTime (from joda library) to Modelio and generate entity using jhipster-uml

Tags: uml, jhipster, modelio

We are using Modelio to create an entity diagram and have it exported as an XMI file.

Once we have the XMI, we can use jhipster uml tool to generate the source.

Since we need a date field in some entities, we added a Data Type called DateTime in Modelio. The intention is to have org.joda.time.DateTime generated in the Java class.

Getting below error while running jhipster url.jhipster-uml test.xmi

```
Parser detected: MODELIO.

    The type 'DateTime' isn't supported by JHipster, exiting now.
    Error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jhipster-uml/lib/exceptions/invalid_type_exception.js:7:34)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

What are we missing here?
I think somehow we need to tell Modelio where/how to map DateTime type to joda class.

Below is the complete XMI file exported via Modelio 3.4.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:JavaExtensions="http:///schemas/JavaExtensions/_UVePsJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng/0" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" xsi:schemaLocation="http:///schemas/JavaExtensions/_UVePsJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng/0 JavaExtensions.profile.xmi#_UVnZp5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng">
  <uml:Model xmi:id="_UVGcQJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" name="test">
    <eAnnotations xmi:id="_UVGcQZdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" source="Objing">
      <contents xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_UVGcQpdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" name="exporterVersion">
        <defaultValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralString" xmi:id="_UVGcQ5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" value="3.0.0"/>
      </contents>
    </eAnnotations>
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_UVGcRJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" name="TestClass">
      <ownedComment xmi:id="_UVGcRZdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng">
        <body>&lt;Enter note text here></body>
      </ownedComment>
      <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_UVGcRpdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" name="testAtt" visibility="public" type="_UVGcR5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" isUnique="false"/>
    </packagedElement>
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:PrimitiveType" xmi:id="_UVGcR5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" name="DateTime"/>
    <profileApplication xmi:id="_UWtl0JdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng">
      <eAnnotations xmi:id="_UWvbAJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" source="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML">
        <references xmi:type="ecore:EPackage" href="JavaExtensions.profile.xmi#_UVnZp5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng"/>
      </eAnnotations>
      <appliedProfile href="JavaExtensions.profile.xmi#_UVnZoJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng"/>
    </profileApplication>
  </uml:Model>
  <JavaExtensions:JavaDataType xmi:id="_UW1hoJdXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" base_DataType="_UVGcR5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng" base_PrimitiveType="_UVGcR5dXEeWrwNWyJ1cDng"/>
</xmi:XMI>
```

Answer (score 0):

jhipster write the dates into a entity using joda library. I think you have to use LocalDate from joda

```
  @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ISO8601LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "fecha")
    private LocalDate fecha;
```